# Do I need a transit visa for a 4-hour layover in London? I have to change airports (Heathrow to London City)

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas

I have a connecting flight Delhi -> London -> Ibiza. The layover in London is for 4 hours 30 mins, during which I have to change airports, from Heathrow to London City. I have gone over the UK government website over and over again and contacted the UK embassy in India. There seems to be no clear answer.

If I have connecting flights with a valid Schengen visa for entry in Spain, do I need a transit visa? If yes, which one?  Direct airside transit visa or Visitor in transit visa?

The website says if you cross border control then you need avisitor in transit visa. If you don't, then a Direct airside transit visa.

Will I be crossing border control?

Comment: Are you sure 4:30 hours are enough? Travelling between airports may take most of it. You should carefully plan it.

Comment: I think LHR-LCY in 4h30 is pushing your luck.  http://tfl.gov.uk says 1h11m in the middle of the day, which involves Heathrow Express (which will be **expensive**); 1h29m if you use the Underground from LHR.  Add on 15m to disembark, 30m to clear customs and immigration (see Hanky's answer), 15m walking time, and you're looking at arriving LCY two hours before departure, **if nothing at all goes wrong**.  It's not impossible, but I'd only do it on a single ticket (ie, if the airline is responsible if you miss the connection) or with very good travel insurance, and lightweight luggage.

Comment: The fact that you are departing from LCY is a good thing as the check-in deadlines there are much shorter than at most other airports, but I agree that you don't have much margin if there are any issues. Also if you are using public transport, it involves 2 or 3 changes, so you should probably budget more time that what is indicated if you have heavy luggage to haul through all those corridors and stairs.

Comment: @MadHatter 2 hours is, if anything, too early to arrive at LCY. The itinerary is well padded.

Comment: @Priyanka You don't state your citizenship or country of permanent residence, so it's quite hard for us to imagine your visa situation. You will certainly be crossing border control.

Comment: @Calchas jcaron disagrees about the padding in that itinerary ("*you don't have much margin if there are any issues*"), as do I.  I guess we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Ground transportation between airports cannot be "airside."

Answer (score 15):

> The website says if you cross border control then you require 'visitor in transit' visa

You will not be airside when you change from Heathrow to City, so you need *Visitor in transit* visa.

> I am not sure if i will be crossing border control ?

This is not a direct airside transit, **you will be** crossing the UK border.